# Echoing out an array and insert blank strings if the key doesn't exist in another array

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
[0]
    {
    Array[0] { First_Name => "john" }
    Array[1] { Last_Name => "smith" }
    Array[2] { Job => "Worker Ant" }
    }
[1]
    {
    Array[0] { First_Name => "jane" }
    Array[1] { Last_Name => "smith" }
    }
```

etc. Let's call it `peopleArray`;

I also have an array of keys such as `"First_Name, Last_Name"` that would match the keys in the above examples. I'll call it `headingArray`.

I want to echo out `peopleArray` seperated by commas like this:

`"'john', 'smith', 'Worker Ant'"`

`'jane','smith',''`

And have the values without keys in the `headingArray` be just an empty string.

I've been trying something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($headingArray); $i++){
    foreach($peopleArray as $row){
        foreach($row as $data){
            if(key($data) == $headingArray[$i]){
                echo '"'.current($data).'",';            
            }
        }
    }
    //die();
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Where I loop through each header and try to match up the values, but it clearly doesn't work.

There must be a simpler way of doing this.

Can anyone help me out/point me in the right direction? I've been pounding my brain on this for hours.

Edit: I've come up with this. It echoes all the values I need, but does some weird thing with skipping the ones that don't exist:

```
foreach($peopleArray as $person) {
    $prevKey = array();
    $numItems = count($person);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($person as $heading) {
        foreach($person as $key => $value) {
            if(key($value) == $heading){
                echo '"'.str_replace(',',' ',current($value)).'",';
                $prevKey[] = key($value);
                break;
            } else if(in_array(key($value), $prevKey)) {

            } else {
                echo '"",';
            }
        }
        //die(var_dump($prevKey));
        $i++;
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

I need it to return a blank string if it doesn't exist.

Comment: To me it looks like you have a strange data structure. Why don't you use an array of arrays instead of an array of arrays of arrays?

Comment: you may use if (empty(key($data))) { echo something; }

Comment: They were originally from POST vars. It's an array of all the data from a form separated by each submitted form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use objects:

```
<?php

class Worker
{
    //without getters/setters, just idea
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $job;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "'".implode("', '", get_object_vars($this))."'";
    }
}

//let's assume we have array of Worker objects

foreach ($Workers as $Worker)
{
    print $Worker.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can do it like this because the headings are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($peopleArray as $p)
    {
        foreach($i=0,$l=count($headingArray);$i<$l;$i++)
            {
                $value = isset($p[$headingArray[$i]]) ? $p[$headingArray[$i]] : '';
                $comma = $i<($l+1) ? ',' : '';
                echo '"' . $value . '"', $comma;
            }
        echo "\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: This just gives me a long string of "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
foreach($peopleArray as $person) {
    foreach($person as $keyValue) {
        foreach($keyValue as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($key, $headingArray)) {
                echo '"'.$value.'", ';
            } else {
                echo '"", ';
            }
        }
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: This just prints out "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array", "Array",

Comment: Ah I expected that, because of the way that your arrays are built. You have put each of the key-value-pairs in a separate array, as it seems. That's not necessary, better try to put all (First_Name, Last_Name, Job) key-value-pairs in one array and add this array directly as a value of the $peopleArray. Then my code should work better.

Comment: If you can't or don't want to change the array-structure, then the following should help: put another foreach-loop around the inner foreach-loop, so you have 3 foreach-loops:
1. ($peopleArray as $person)
2. ($person as $keyValue)
3. ($keyValue as $key => $value)
then it should work with the array-structure that you (seem to) have right now.

Comment: This would be fine, but I need to return blank values too if they don't exist. I've updated my function above.

Comment: You can do so by adding an else-case to the if-block. I've edited my answer above. Is it working for you now?